# Проблема в логике (if ... else)

Tags: java, классы, if

Проблема такова: Необходимо написать класс, который принимает с клавиатуры два целых числа и, если оба имеют одинаковый знак, на экран выводится сообщение "Один и тот же знак", а если разный, то на экран выводится сообщение "Разные знаки". Если хотя бы одно из чисел равно 0, выводится "Некорректно"

Суть проблемы в том, что не до конца понимаю, как сделать так, чтобы оператор if сравнивал именно ЗНАКИ, а не числа. Выручайте, прошу.

Answer (score 1):

Например, так:

```
if (x1 > 0) { 
   x1 = 1;
} else if (x1 < 0) { 
   x1 = -1;
}
```

Теперь независимо от того, каким x1 было изначально, теперь там `-1`, `0` или `1`. Тоже самое делайте с другим числом и потом уже сравнивайте между собой.

Comment: Я благодарен Вам, о мудрец непокорного Java - языка. Вы наставили меня на верный путь. Низкий поклон таким, как Вы, познавший всю глубину этого языка

Answer (score 0):

Меньше 0 = знак минус.

Больше 0 = знак плюс.

0 = 0.